# Application.OnTime isn't running automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to close my workbook after a certain amount of time.

I'm using 10 seconds for now just to test it but it's not working automatically.

I have to run the code once by myself.

here's my code in module.

```
Public Sub fermeoutil()

Workbooks("OUTIL_CRN.xlsm").Save
Workbooks("OUTIL_CRN.xlsm").Close
Call test
End Sub

Sub test()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "fermeoutil"

End Sub
```

Comment: *I have to run the code once by myself.* Yes, your code `test` must be run once for the timing event to exist in the first place. The call to `test` in `fermeoutil` is not needed. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime)

Comment: @TomBrunberg Is there a way to have in run automatically? Without having to do anything ? Thank you

Comment: To run automatically when the workbook is opened, write the code in `Thisworkbook`, in event `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`

Comment: if the sub's name `Workbook_Open` , how do I name the procedure for `Application.OnTime`? @TomBrunberg

Comment: Exactly as you have it now? I'm not sure I understand why you ask.

Comment: U said to use `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`. So what happen's with 'fermeoutil'. I can't call it anymore since it's not the name of the sub. @TomBrunberg

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake now. I meant to write: *write the code **of test()** in Thisworkbook, in event Private Sub Workbook_Open*. With the implied meaning to leave the `fermeoutil` where you have it now. Sorry for my unclear wording. For clarity I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ThisWorkbook` add procedure Workbook_Open with following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "fermeoutil"
End Sub
```

In `Module1` keep your current procedure `fermeoutil()` removing the call to `test`:

```
Public Sub fermeoutil()
    Workbooks("OUTIL_CRN.xlsm").Save
    Workbooks("OUTIL_CRN.xlsm").Close
End Sub
```

Your call to `test` (or Workbook_Open() as it is now called), is not needed, as you have left out the last argument of `Application.OnTime`, namely `Schedule` which is optional and has a default value of `True` meaning the event will be recurring. Not sure if that really is your meaning, since you are closing the wb.

Comment: It is still not working... Did everything you said !

Comment: Well, it works for me, I copied the codes from a working test.

Comment: it worked. I just had to run the macro once. now it works automatically without having to run it. Thanks a lot.